# Changing default body for methods generated from implementing interface methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ creates methods with a default implementation when selecting this dialog:

[image: dialog screenshot]

If the method's return type is void, the method is empty, otherwise the method returns the default value for the return type:

[image: default implementations]

How can I change the generated methods to look like this:

[image: what i want]

I already tried changing the File and Code Template "New Method Body" under
`Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates` for both the default and project scheme, but that didn't change anything, the methods are generated like before:

[image: file and code templates dialogue]

What am I missing, what do I have to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template for the **Implement methods** action is located under the point **Implemented Method Body** (Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Tab Code).

The **New Method Body** template is for the **Create method** action:

[image]